# How are namespace objects used alongside AMD in javascript?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

In an effort to make my libraries more portable I've been reading up on AMD and CommonJS. The one thing I have noticed above all is the way they use a directory structure and aim to have one module per file. From what I can tell their 'namespaces' coincide with the directory tree.

However, my own code uses a global object as a namespace, then among my various files, regardless of the directories, I add classes to this object.

```
(function (Twifty) {
    // Add objects to the Twifty namespace
    return Twifty;
}(Twifty || {}));
```

In the upgrade effort, I'm trying to support AMD and CommonJs. There are many articles out there about how to this, but I can't wrap my head around the AMD [define](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD#define-function-) function. Here is how I am transforming the above code:

```
(function (root, factory) {

    // Define the namespace if it doesn't exist
    var Twifty = root.Twifty || {};

    'use strict';
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD is used - Register as an anonymous module.
        define([], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        // CommonJS is used - Twifty is a namespace and doesn't need to be required
        factory(Twifty);
    } else {
        // Neither AMD nor CommonJS used. Use global variables.
        if (!document) {
            throw 'twifty-map requires a DOM object';
        }
        root.Twifty = factory(Twifty);
    }

}(this, function(Twifty) {
    // Add objects to the Twifty namespace
    return Twifty;
}));
```

The problem is with the AMD `define`. The factory requires a `Twifty` object but since it is not a module I can't add it as a dependency. How should I handle this?

It's not really feasable to remove the namespace as this would break any code that depends on it.

Sorry in advance if this is a trivial question.

Comment: Is there any reason `root.Twifty` should exist when your library is loaded as an AMD module? See, one of the reasons to use AMD is to prevent having everything in the global space. For hysterical reasons, some old libraries that are designed to load as AMD libraries do leak into the global space by default (e.g. jQuery). Usually that's because there are third-party extensions (e.g. jQuery plugins) that would not work otherwise, because when the extensions were created, the library they extend did not support AMD. For new libraries, you **really** should avoid leaking into the global space.

Comment: @Louis That makes sense. From what I understand, the object are passed around rather than being attached. But, I still come back to the same problem of where to create the `Twifty` object. The code should support AMD, but not be stuck to it. IE, all files should still work if they are include into a web page using the standard `<script>` method.

Comment: I should be able to come up with something if someone does not beat me to it. I'm in the midst of work right now so it may take a bit before I can post. I wanted to make sure first there was not some substantial reason to have `root.Twifty` exist *even* when the code is loaded as an AMD module. (New libraries *should* not leak into the global space but there are *sometimes* good substantial reasons to do so. I have over 100 AMD modules written and purposely leaked into the global space even when loaded as an AMD module only once that I recall.)

Comment: The `root.Twifty` is just my attempt to understand this problem. As it is now, `Twifty` is a property of `window`, so once it's created it's available to all subsequent files. Here, however, without it being attached to something it will be limited to the scope of the function. Passing it around wouldn't be a problem in my own code (soon to be modules), but for external code depending on a `window` property, it still needs to be global.

Comment: It is perfectly fine for the `else` branch (not-AMD, not-CommonJS) to use the global space.

Comment: @Louis, Funny thing is, I started using the namespace in an effort to not pollute the global space. Now, it's coming back to bite me in the *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an AMD or CommonJS context, your modules should not leak variables into the global space.

So a strategy has to be used in order to have a common object (the namespace) that the various modules can add to.

You can have a `twifty.base` module like this:

```
(function (root) {
    'use strict';

    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD 
        define([], {});
    }
    else if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports) {
        // CommonJS
        module.exports = {};
    } 
    else {
        root.Twifty = root.Twifty || {};
    }
}(this));
```

All other modules would depend on `twifty.base`:

```
(function (root, factory) {

    'use strict';
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD
        define(['twifty.base'], factory);
    }
    else if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports) {
        // CommonJS
        module.exports = factory(require('twifty.base'));
    } 
    else {
        root.Twifty = factory(root.Twifty || {});
    }

}(this, function(Twifty) {
    Twifty.foo = 1;

    Twifty.bar = function () {};

    return Twifty;
}));
```

In an environment where modules are not used, the `script` elements could load the scripts in any order and `twifty.base` would actually not be *needed*. (Because `factory(root.Twifty || {})`.) In an AMD or CommonJS environment, since all modules depend on `twifty.base`, and since modules in AMD and CommonJS environments are singletons, then all modules are extending the same JavaScript object.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'd have preferred not to have the extra module, but I guess that's the price of staying backwards compatible. Thinking about it though, when packages get a major version update, it should be simple enough remove.